# Why does Typescript handle interface functions differently if defined as an arrow function vs attribute?

Tags: typescript

Given two different handling functions which handle two different types of objects with a shared base interface, I want to create a mapping between the type enum and the handlers. If the `GenericHandler.handle()` is defined as an anonymous function the code won't compile (`Type 'EventType' is not assignable to type 'EventType.A'.` on the mapping attributes). However simply changing the interface to what I understand to be exactly equivalent fixes the issue:

```js
interface GenericHandlerInterface<T extends Base = Base> {
    handle(args: { event: T }): void;
}
```

What causes this difference?

Full example:

```js
enum EventType {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}
interface Base {
    type: EventType;
}

interface A extends Base {
    type: EventType.A;
}

interface B extends Base {
    type: EventType.B;
}

const aHandlerInterface: GenericHandlerInterface<A> = {
    handle: ({ event }) => {
        console.log(event);
    },
};
const bHandlerInterface: GenericHandlerInterface<B> = {
    handle: ({ event }) => {
        console.log(event);
    },
};

const handlerMappingInterface: { [key in EventType]: GenericHandlerInterface } = {
    [EventType.A]: aHandlerInterface,
    [EventType.B]: bHandlerInterface,
};

interface GenericHandlerInterface<T extends Base = Base> {
    handle: (args: { event: T }) => void;
}
```

Comment: Even with `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled, method parameters are checked bivariantly instead of the safer contravariant check that function-valued properties undergo. See the answers to the linked questions for more information.